# Custom material disagne stile for button

Tags: android, button, styles, material-design

I need create custom style for my button and use material desgn. I have button:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enterText"/>
```

I create style like [this](https://materialdoc.com/components/buttons/#how-to-add) in styles and styles v21

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#e10a0a</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#48d91b</item>
</style>
```

[image]

But my button look like this:

[image]

who will be able to explain the difference and what is better? 1. use the style. 2. write your own drawable?

Comment: your defined colors aren't used in button styles I think

Comment: thank the captain of the evidence

Comment: no problems. I mean why you think that `colorControlHighlight` and `colorButtonNormal` are the color names used by the button style?

Comment: Yes, I do not know) I'm just trying to do the same as in the example article that I cited in the question

Comment: Are you sure you added the appcompat library? Also is this a preview or a screenshot from the device (with non-styled button)?

Comment: Of course I'm sure